# My networkx graph is not displaying nodes with zero degree

Tags: python

I have written a simple python program using network library to display a graph. I used Graphviz for visualization.

Here is the code

```
import networkx as nx

from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import write_dot

G2 = nx.read_edgelist("test_input.txt",create_using=nx.DiGraph())



write_dot(G2,"test_flow.doc")
diagram = 'print (os.system("D:/graphviz/bin/dot -o ' + output.svg + ' -Tsvg ' + test_flow.doc + '"))'

exec(diagram)
```

test_input

```
A 

B   C

B   D

D   E
```

[Output from graphviz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dagY.jpg)

In this case, my dotfile is not storing node "A".

Nodes with degree 0 are not getting displayed. Could someone help me in this?

Comment: Sorry, did not understand... Is node A in the dot file? Could you post it?

Comment: Find below the output of the below command. 

print (G2.nodes())

['B', 'D', 'E', 'C']

I mean to say the graph itself is storing node "A". That's the reason why it is not written to Dot file.
Dot file
strict digraph "" {
D;
E;
B;
C;
D -> E;
B -> D;
B -> C;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is directly from the networkx code. As you can see, only "path" can be read with that command. Every line containing less than two "words" is ignored.

> From the source file:

```
for line in lines:
    p=line.find(comments)
    if p>=0:
        line = line[:p]
    if not len(line):
        continue
    # split line, should have 2 or more
    s=line.strip().split(delimiter)
    if len(s)<2:
        continue
    u=s.pop(0)
    v=s.pop(0)
    d=s
```

This function is actually in `parse_edgelist`. The function `read_edgelist` is just a wrapper around the function I posted.

I think the best way is to parse manually the file, retrieving the "single" nodes and add them manually to the graph.

Comment: Thank you Ricc. Now i am able to find the reason why nodes with degree "0" are missing. 

Instead of parsing manually i modified the input and used 'read_adjlist', This way my problem got resolved. Thanks again for your inputs/suggestion.